# MonoDevelop unsupported project type vcxproj

Tags: visual-c++, mono

I have been a long-time visual studio developer, and I am trying to switch over to using mono  so I can port my applications to Ubuntu. I have been trying to get some of my VS2010 C++ projects (.vcxproj file types) to load into MD on my Ubunutu 12.04 machine. According to the documentation I have read online this should work, however, every time I try and load a project I get the error shown below. Is there something else I need to be installing in order to be able to load C++ projects in monodevelop? I have done some searching, but have not yet found anything related to this particular question.

VC2010Test.sln(4): Unsupported or unrecognized project : '/home/me/Projects/Test/VC2010Test/VC2010Test.vcxproj'.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a C++/CLI project?

Comment: The error message leaves little to the imagination.  At least check the "No" entries in [this table](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Feature_List).  You can turn them in a Yes, they are waiting for your check-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoDevelop has a C/C++ binding, called CBinding.

But:

- Beware, it's not meant to target managed C++.
- AFAIK, it only works in Unix-like platforms.

So, if you still target non-managed C++ and are not using MonoDevelop for Windows, two questions:

- Did you make sure that the binding (addin) is installed and enabled?
- If the answer to the above question is yes, you may want to try this: the binding creates projects with the extension ".proj" by default, I think, so maybe you can change this to ".vcxproj", recompile, and test again. If it works, then it should be easy to create a pull request to include this extension of possible file types that this addin can handle?

Comment: It is a pure c++ project, no cli. The documentation I have read says that mono does not support managed c++, but that is should work with vcxproj, but not vcproj files. So yes, I am targeting MonoDevelop on Ubuntu and I do have the C/C++ Language bindings V 2.8.6.3 installed. I can create a c++ project, compile it, and debug it in MD. It creates it as a .cproj file. I tried what you suggested of renaming the file to vcxproj, and that does not work. It simply loads that file in as a text file. I also tried changing the .vcxproj file to be .cproj, and that did not work either.

Comment: I didn't tell you to rename anything, I told you to dive in the sources of the CBinding addin, and rename the ".cproj" handler to ".vcxproj" wherever it might be